# Crear Separador Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy haciendo una interfaz en Python que varias pestañas para lo que he usado .Notebook, dentro de cara pestaña hay una seri de botones, labes, combos, etc pero necesito colocar un separador para poder darle una segmentación a lo que se ve en cada pestaña, pero realmente no he podido encontrar la forma que aparezca una separación entre cada fila, esto es parte del codigo

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.title("Titulo de la ventana principal")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.geometry('700x400')

frame = ttk.Notebook(root)
frame.grid()
window0 = ttk.Frame(frame)
window1 = ttk.Frame(frame)
frame.add(window0,text="Pestaña 1")
frame.add(window1,text="Pestaña 2")

Label(window0,text="Etiqueta 1").grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="w")
Button(window0, text="Boton 1",command="buscar").grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="w")
**Visto graficamente aca deberia existir un separador**
Label(window0,text="Etiqueta 2").grid(row=2,column=0,sticky="w")
Button(window0, text="Boton 2",command="buscar").grid(row=0,column=2,sticky="w")
**Visto graficamente aca deberia existir un separador**


Label(window1,text="Etiqueta 1").grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="w")
Button(window1, text="Boton 1",command="buscar").grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="w")
**Visto graficamente aca deberia existir un separador**
Label(window1,text="Etiqueta 2").grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="w")
Button(window1, text="Boton 2",command="buscar").grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="w")
**Visto graficamente aca deberia existir un separador**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar `ttk.Separator` que crea una línea vertical u horizontal sin más, pero lo más importante es que dejes una fila entre ambos grupos y le asignes un tamaño mínimo para crear un espaciado entre ambas:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Titulo de la ventana principal")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.geometry('700x400')

frame = ttk.Notebook(root)
frame.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
window0 = ttk.Frame(frame)

frame.add(window0,text="Pestaña 1")

tk.Label(
    window0, text="Etiqueta 1"
    ).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsw")
tk.Button(window0, text="Boton 1", command="buscar"
          ).grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="w")

ttk.Separator(
    window0, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL
    ).grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="EW")


tk.Label(window0, text="Etiqueta 2"
         ).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="nsw")
tk.Button(
    window0, text="Boton 2",command="buscar"
    ).grid(row=3, column=2, sticky="w")


window0.grid_rowconfigure(0, minsize=15)
window0.grid_columnconfigure(1, minsize=5)
window0.grid_rowconfigure(2, minsize=15)  # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas Gracias, esto resolvio mi duda